# Deprecation 6720 - Experimental feature for requested-permissions in capsule-info.bxb

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I updated my Bixby capsule-info.bxb to add the requested-permissions element but studio is complaining with this error:

```
Experimental feature, not available for external use. [deprecation 6720]
```

The hyperlink below the error message results in an HTTP 404 Not Found page (https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/release-notes/deprecations.6720)

I made this change as requested in a *Stage 2 Deprecation Warning* email.

[image: Screen Shot showing error]

Comment: Could you please share the capsule-info.bxb result such error?

Comment: I added a screen shot above

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved. Please see [this Help Center article](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043439973) for more information.